To use Netlink sockets in hostapd and the driver, initialize and configure the socket, then implement message handling for kernel-user communication
To use the Netlink socket in hostapd and the driver, you need to initialize the Netlink socket in the driver, create and configure the Netlink socket in hostapd, and implement appropriate message handling functions to facilitate communication between the kernel and user-space processes.
any example and clear path for learning the netlink-socket completely?
